# Azure REST Api 500 Internal Server Error when creating a app service slot in a virtual network

Tags: azure, rest, azure-web-app-service

I've got an issue when creating a slot via the Azure REST Api found [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/create-or-update-slot)

If I specify a `virtualNetworkSubnetId` property in the body of the request I get a 500 error with a generic "An Error Occurred" message.  Full body is below.

```
{
  "identity": {
    "type": "SystemAssigned"
  },
  "kind": "app,linux,container",
  "location": "westeurope",
  "properties": {
    "httpsOnly": true,
    "hyperV": false,
    "isXenon": false,
    "reserved": false,
    "scmSiteAlsoStopped": false,
    "siteConfig": {
      "acrUseManagedIdentityCreds": true,
      "alwaysOn": true,
      "http20Enabled": true,
      "ipSecurityRestrictions": [
        {
          "action": "Allow",
          "name": "AllowApim",
          "priority": 100,
          "vnetSubnetResourceId": "<apim subnet id>"
        }
      ],
      "linuxFxVersion": "<docker latest image>",
      "localMySqlEnabled": false,
      "minTlsVersion": "1.2",
      "netFrameworkVersion": "v4.6"
    },
    "storageAccountRequired": false,
    "virtualNetworkSubnetId": "<backend subnet id>"
  }
}
```

If I remove the `virtualNetworkSubnetId` property then the request returns a 200.  The weird thing is I can then issue an update with the property in it and it assigns the slot to the subnet correctly.

Note I only see this on the slot not on the parent app service.

I was expecting either this to be successful or an error message which I could identify the underlying cause.

Answer (score 0):

- Well `virtualNetworkSubnetId` is NOT in the following format

```
"virtualNetworkSubnetId": "<backend subnet id>"
```

- According to this [MSDOC](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/appservice/web-apps/create-or-update-slot#:%7E:text=properties.virtualNetworkSubnetId,azure_auth) the `virtualNetworkSubnetId` is in the followoing format:

```
/subscriptions/{subscriptionName}/resourceGroups/{resourceGroupName}/providers/Microsoft.Network/virtualNetworks/{vnetName}/subnets/{subnetName}
```

After using the above format, I was able to get the following output:

[image]

- Also make sure that you have Delegated the subnet which you are using here to `Microsoft.web/serverFrams`. To do this go to your vnet in your azure portal then click on `subnets` tab then click on the subnet you are using then a popup will emerge where select `Microsoft.web/serverFrams` and save.

[image]

- Also, you can use your subscription Id instead of Subscription name int format

Comment: The line <backend subnet id> was just me redacting the actual value so there wasn't any sensitive data in it.  I can confirm that the subnet delegation is in place as well.

Comment: When you are send the call to REST api you must be getting a response with the error can you please share that